# Prevent seeing other tenants in store homepage

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I want to use the WSO2 EMM product in a multi-tenant setup. I have defined two tenants and I can login in with their specific users and publish apps. But when I go to the store (https://...:9443/store) I see all tenants and carbon.super.

What do I have to change to hide the tenants and rename carbon.super to anything else (or hide it too) for anonymous users?

Kind regards,
Paul

Comment: what is your emm version?

Comment: It is the latest, version 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the expected behavior for the product.

However still you can customize the store Jaggery app (which located in {EMM_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store) and edit the page to match your requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: I will have a look at it. Thanks.